# Disabling empathy balloon

Tags: empathy, notify-osd

How can I disable empathy's notification balloon that shows up when someone sends me a message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you see the contact list, click "edit > preferences". You should uncheck "Enable bubble notifications". The balloon will not pop up anymore. You can also customize which balloons you want to see and which not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck

```
Edit->Preferences->Notifications->Enable bubble notifications
```